# Read uploaded pptx file with Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to build a website where one can upload a .pptx file, and a few aspects would be checked (e.g. slide count). I have the Open XML SDK 2.5 and I have added a reference to it. Yet, when I try to use commands from the SDK, they are not available.

(Also, do I really need a memory stream to process the file? I don't want to store the files, just extract some details from them.)

My code is in VB, but I can read C# too:

```
Partial Class uploadpresentation
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Protected Sub Upload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Upload.Click
    If PptxUpload.HasFile AndAlso PptxUpload.FileName.EndsWith(".pptx") Then
        ProcessFile(PptxUpload.PostedFile)
    End If
 End Sub

 Sub ProcessFile(ByVal pptxFile As HttpPostedFile)

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())

    Using doc As PresentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(fileName, False)

    outputMessage = "Number of slides: " & argh

 End Sub
End Class
```

My Web.config has this:

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
```

So, neither MemoryStream, nor PresentationDocument is recognised. What am I missing here?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wered question, but, 
Have you add import section?

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
```

Are you using references form the gac or storing OpenXml dlls as files?

Comment: This was it. I have added the reference, but completely forgot about the imports part. I have been "programming" in VBA for the past 2 years, and it has mutilated my brain. It's like I have to relearn programming all over again. Thanks for the help. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Also, I'm using dll-s. Is there an advantage in using gac? This will be a very basic landing site with one aspx page, some javascript, and that's it.

Comment: Usually using dlls is better , otherwise you'll  have to install OpenXml on the server

Comment: I'll stick with dlls. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The uploaded file comes as a stream, until you actually write it to a location. You don't do that in the code provided in the question. You can just pass the stream property of [`HttpPostedFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) to the `Open` method.

Here's how you should be able to get the slide count (C#):

```
public void ProcessFile(HttpPostedFile pptxFile)
{
    int slideCount = 0;

    using (var doc = PresentationDocument.Open(pptxFile.InputStream, false))
    {
        PresentationPart presentationPart = doc.PresentationPart;
        slideCount = presentationPart.SlideParts.Count();
    }
}
```

For more information, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850842.aspx) about retrieving slide count.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My problem is far more basic: when I add a reference to the Open XML SDK, it should become available in intellisense code suggestions. But for me, it does not. I start typing `presentationdocument`, but nothing happens, so I assume it is not recognised. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?